# Django 1.7 show links to change forms in a inline tablur view

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a inline tabular view (GenericTabularInline) inside a ModelAdmin class. I  need to add links to change forms in that inline table view. Here is some refrence code

```
class StudentActionInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = StudentActionInline
    ordering = ('roll_no',)


class CaptainAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        StudentActionInline
    ]
```

I would like to add a link to change the student model (a form to change the student model) inside the inline tabular view. This is in Django 1.7

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Student model is registered with the admin and you would just like to add a link to the change page of a student instance associated with the StudentActionInline in the inline form? I assume that StudentActionInline has a fk to Student?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's encouraged but here's how I've solved that in the past.

```
class StudentActionInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = StudentActionInline
    ordering = ('roll_no',)

    def edit_student(self, obj):
        # Use the obj here to get a student pk and the admin url
        return '<a href="link_goes_here">Edit student</a>'
    edit_student.allow_tags = True
    edit_student.short_description = 'Edit student'

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super(StudentActionInline, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)

        if obj and obj.pk:
            # It's important to not make modifications
            # to the fields directly.
            fields = list(fields) + ['edit_student']
        return fields
```

Django admin allows for "dynamic" readonly fields so I modified the get_readonly_fields method to only add the edit_student field if the student action exists vs is new (no pk), this is to avoid having a student action with no student attached to it yet since it's blank.

Note that if your admin definition for `StudentActionInline` has fields or fieldsets defined then you'll have to add the edit_student there as well.